# conditional operator in $log.debug

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a conditional operator in the debug statement, but the log is not printing completely.

It prints only "passed" or "failed",  and couldnt get full log message as "Form validation: passed"...

```
$log.debug("Form Validation: " + (isValid)?"passed":"failed");
```

Comment: use this `$log.debug("Form Validation: " , (isValid)?"passed":"failed");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of the operator precedence for `+` is higher than for the conditional operator, so it evaluates as

```
("Form Validation: " + (isValid))?"passed":"failed"
```

Which always evaluates `("Form Validation: " + (isValid))` to a truthy value and returns `passed` as a result of the whole expression.

The solution for you would be to add parentheses around the second part of the concatenation expression:

```
"Form Validation: " + (isValid ? "passed" : "failed")
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence